# highlight a single cell in a table generated with Guide - Matlab

Tags: matlab, uitableview, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to highlight or color the background of a single cell in a table generated with guide. is there a way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by putting html code in the cell data, there is a guide on the MATLAB site with an example, but IMHO it's not very elegant way of doing it as it makes the content a string and hides the data. It makes any subsequent data handling very awkward as you have to start separating out the html code.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-D782JW/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-D782JW

So the content of the cell ends up like this

```
<html><font color="blue">'my text'</font></html>
```

So a worked example to clarify the comments, as I realised that the example above colours the text and not the background as requested.

```
scores=cell(7,10);
scores(3,4)={'<html><font bgcolor=#FF8800>my text</font></html>'}
f=figure
uit = uitable(f, 'Data', scores,'Units', 'normalized','Position', [0 0 1 1]);
```

This creates the cell array of scores with one cell html inserted. When you create the uitable you set the property 'Data' to this cell array. If you have already created your table via guide then you should have a handle to the table object, in which case you should be able to use set

```
set(uitableHandle,'Data',scores);
```

As I said it's a bit messy and doesn't work that well as it just colours the text background rather than the entire cell but I think that's the best you'll get with using the native MATLAB GUI widgets.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I asked if there is a way to this for table generated with guide and this is not the case.

Comment: It depends what you mean a "table generated with guide". I agree you cannot edit the cell property directly via the property editor in guide, however at some point you will have to write some code to go behind your GUI. In which case a table generated in guide can be modified by the MATLAB code to provide the cell highlighting requested. When you use guide all it's doing is creating an uitable, it's properties can then be modified as explained in the link I provided.

Comment: so how can I do this? let's say that I have 7x10 array and I  want to color the cell [3,4]. I tried in several ways, one of them was scores(3,4) = ['<html><font color="blue">'my text'</font></html>'], of course it did not work. Any suggestions...